# Booting into terminal after Virtualbox installation (OpenSuse)

Tags: kernel, boot, virtualbox, opensuse

I was attempting to install Virtualbox, using Zypper. The installation went fine, until I restarted my computer. On boot, instead of the regular GUI, I get a console, specifically stating:

> Kernel 6.3.2-1-default (tty1)

I am able to access BASH, but that's it. I am hoping to boot back into the regular GUI.

I haven't tried anything as to not break my system any further. Any/all help is greatly appreciated. For reference, I am using OpenSuse Tumbleweed.

EDIT: I ran a `sudo zypper dup`, and upon reboot, my system was working as normal. I'm not sure what caused the issue, but if anyone is running into the same issue, this may be a solution.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl get-default`?

Comment: The output is: `graphical.target`.

Comment: Check the logs under `/var/log` or by using `journalctl` (as root). Also maybe you have display-manager.service, if so, then try checking its logs by using `sudo journalctl -xeu display-manager.service` maybe this service is failing to start.

Comment: Also try switching between different virtual consoles by using `Ctrl` + `alt` + `fn` (for example `Ctrl alt f7`)

Comment: Using `sudo journalctl -xeu display-manger.server`, I can see that display-manager.service begun and finished execution successfully. As for switching between virtual consoles, I'm able to switch between `Ctrl alt f1` to `Ctrl alt f6`. There does not appear to be any difference between them.

Comment: And what about running directly the command used by display-manager? Try running: `/usr/lib/X11/display-manager start` (I also have OpenSuse Tw) so the command should be the same.

Comment: I try installing virtualbox as well and I did no have any problem, maybe there some errors with the systemd services used by virtualbox. Do you have virtualization enabled in your computer? (this is enabled/disabled via BIOS).

Comment: Also try checking the logs of `vboxautostart-service.service`, `vboxdrv.service` and `vboxweb-service.service` by using `systemctl status the_service` and `sudo journalctl -xeu the_service` commands.

Comment: I decided to run a `zypper dup`, I thought maybe if there was outdated or missing packages they would be reinstalled. I'm still not sure what caused the issue, but it is fixed now. Upon reboot, I was able to get the GUI back as normal. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Glad to know that! And since you have solved the issue it should be better to post that as an answer (instead of the question).